# How to fetch records from an Oracle table in a chunked way using Akka?

Tags: java, oracle, akka

I am trying to learn Akka from a use case perspective .
I have a table in Oracle which contains 8 million records .

I want to retrieve the records in a chunked fashion , process them and then receive the next chunk .

E.g. :

- I want to fetch 3000 records .
- Process the 3000 records and pause the load of DB objects into memory .
- Once the 3000 records are processed, I want to open the stream again and fetch the next chunk of 3000 records, process it  and so on and so forth .

I am extremely new to Akka , hence I am wondering is that something that Akka can help me with ?

Comment: No, Akka would not help you.  Akka helps in massively parallel tasks (>10000 parallel activities), and you have single activity, which can be implemented comfortably as a thread (rather than an actor).

Comment: Yes, that can work with Akka Stream. You need a source that can read from Oracle, e.g. using slick (https://scala-slick.org/doc/3.3.1/dbio.html#streaming) and then process the elements one by one. It will not be batch processing, though, but in a streaming fashion, so that one element is processed after the other. In any case, it should constrain the amount of memory used at any single point in time.